# Probability of pairwise difference of samples from distribution with finite support

Tags: probability, distributions, sampling, bounds

I'd appreciate any help on the following problem:

Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N$ be i.i.d. continuous random variables with support $[0, 1]$.

What is a reasonable bound on the probability that some pair of random variables is less than $\epsilon$ apart? Mathematically, I'd like to find some $\delta$ not too large such that

$$\Pr \left( \exists_{i,j:\ i\ne j}\ |X_i - X_j| < \epsilon \right) < \delta.$$

If it helps, I'm not interested in the general case -- I'm only interested in the cases of a uniform distribution, a truncated Gaussian distribution, and a beta distribution.

Again, I only need a reasonable probability bound, not the exact probability. A friend suggested that the Dirichlet distribution could possibly be helpful here, but I haven't seen a way to apply it here.

Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: You are looking for an upper bound of the distribution function of the "smallest interpoint distance" $M_N$, a statistic which was investigated by many, e.g. by Kanagawa et al. (http://www.ism.ac.jp/editsec/aism/pdf/044_1_0121.pdf). Their Theorem 2.2. provides the exact limit distribution of $M_n$ as $N \to \infty$ for quite general $X_i$. This is not exactly what you are looking for, but maybe generates some good ideas. A quick simulation ($N = 3$, $\epsilon = 0.1$ and the uniform distribution) could not verify the solution by @Max. The last equation in Ray's approach needs clarification.

Comment: @Max Please post answers in the answer forms rather than as comments.  Brandon, because your English statement of your question and your $\TeX$ formula sharply differed, I have taken the liberty of correcting the formula to match the English.  Please check that it states your problem correctly. Finally, I would just like to observe that $\delta$ depends on the essential supremum of the PDF; there (obviously) can be no universal bound that is true for all distributions supported on $[0,1]$.

Comment: @MichaelMayer thanks for the comment and the link.

Comment: @MichaelMayer -- Thank you very much for that link -- it definitely generated some good directions to other papers that I am looking into now. Thanks!!

Comment: @whuber -- pardon my poor math, but would you mind explaining how your new formula differs from the original? I don't quite see the difference.  Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelMayer If all the interpoint distances are ≥ $\epsilon$ then the range -- i.e., the distance from the smallest $X$ to the largest $X$ -- must be ≥ $(n-1)\epsilon$ because there are $n-1$ steps from one ordered $X$ to the next, and each step is ≥ $\epsilon$.

Comment: @RayKoopman: Great idea! Equality between probabilities is lost though. (A large range does not imply a large smallest spacing)

Comment: @MichaelMayer Right. Comment deleted.

Comment: The original formula asked for the chance that *all* pairs of points were within $\epsilon$ of one another. There is a vast gulf between the quantifiers "all" and "some"!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP wrote:

> Let $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_N$ be i.i.d. continuous random variables with support $[0, 1]$. 
>   What is a reasonable bound on the probability that some pair of random variables is less than ϵ apart? ... interested in the cases of a uniform distribution ... I only need a reasonable probability bound, not the exact probability

### For the Uniform case:

I propose the following approximation:

$$\Pr \left( \exists_{i,j:\ i\ne j}\ |X_i - X_j| < \epsilon \right) \approx 1-(1-\epsilon )^{n (n-1)}$$

### Performance

Here is a quick comparison of the proposed APPROXIMATE solution $1-(1-\epsilon )^{n (n-1)}$ posited here, ... compared to the 'actual' probability calculated via Monte Carlo simulations (in each case, `500,000` samples of size $n$):

---

Case 1:   $\epsilon = 0.01$ and $n = 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 16$

```
Approx:  {0.0199,   0.0585199, 0.113615, 0.182093, 0.430399, 0.910371}
Monte:   {0.019478, 0.058606,  0.115204, 0.184624, 0.441432, 0.92556}
```

---

Case 2:   $\epsilon = 0.03$ and $n = 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 16$

```
Approx:  {0.0591,   0.167028, 0.306158, 0.456206, 0.818358, 0.999331}
Monte:   {0.05871,  0.16875,  0.315202, 0.473064, 0.848328, 0.999938}
```

---

Case 3:   $\epsilon = 0.05$ and $n = 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 16$

```
Approx:  {0.0975,   0.264908, 0.45964,  0.641514, 0.943438, 0.999995}
Monte:   {0.097572, 0.269868, 0.479214, 0.672386, 0.967794, 1.}
```

---

Case 4:   $\epsilon = 0.1$ and $n = 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 16$

```
Approx:  {0.19,    0.468559, 0.71757,  0.878423, 0.997261, 1.}
Monte:   {0.19069, 0.487214, 0.759996, 0.92185,  0.999922, 1.}
```

The performance seems surprisingly good for such a simple approximation. I would be interested to know if any better approximations exist (published or otherwise).

---

### Derivation

We are given $X$ ~ Uniform(0,1) with pdf $f(x)$:

[image]

Let $(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n)$ denote a random sample of size $n$ drawn on $X$, and let $(X_{(1)}, X_{(2)}, \dots, X_{(n)})$ be the order statistics, such that $(X_{(1)} < X_{(2)} < \dots < X_{(n)})$.

The joint pdf of the order statistics $X_{(r)}$ and  $X_{(s)}$, for $r < s$, is say $g(x_{(r)},x_{(s)})$:

[image]

where `OrderStat` is a mathStatica function which I am using to automate the mechanical aspects of the calculations.

We are interested to find a pair of random variables that are so close to each other that they are separated by less than $\epsilon$. The two closest random variables in the sample $(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n)$ must *necessarily* be adjoining order statistics, say $X_{(r)}$ and  $X_{(r+1)}$. Replacing $s$ with $r + 1$ in the previous result simplifies the joint pdf to:

[image]

Then $P((X_{(r+1)} - X_{(r)}) < \epsilon)$ is:

[image]

Note that there is no need to specify the probability using absolute values, as we are working with the *ordered* sample.

Thus far, we have calculated the probability that the distance between the $r$th and $(r+1)$th adjoining order statistics is smaller than $\epsilon$. But we do not have only 1 such chance ... there are $(n-1)$ such combinations of adjacent ordered statistics to choose from, ... which suggests the following approximation, as a sort of geometric-style modification to the previous result:

$$\approx 1-(1-\epsilon )^{n (n-1)}$$

The above accuracy / performance comparison suggests it works surprisingly well.

In the case of $n=2$, there is no approximation, and the result should be theoretically exact.